# Using AWK to filter a complex line

Tags: unix, awk, command

I'm new to AWK, I need to save in a file the value of the field "values" from this output

```
'{"extraLeveling":1,"columnNames":["count(userId)"],"values":[[13]]}'
```

In this case I need the 13, how could I do this using awk?
I tryed by doing awk -F',' '{print $4} but definitely I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please post your efforts which you have put in order to solve your own problem, kindly do edit your question and do let us know then.

Comment: That looks like json, have you tried using `jq` on it?

Comment: Who tell you to use 'awk' here ? :)

Comment: I thought on using awk, but maybe there is a better way, I have to use that number to be sent afterwards in a json that I'm sending with curl.

Comment: you really should learn `jq`, but if your desperate, `echo '{"extraLeveling":1,"columnNames":["count(userId)"],"values":[[13]]}'| awk '-F[[]' '{num=$4;sub(/]]}/,"",num); print num}'` produces `13` as output. When one-little-thing changes in your input, you can count on this to break! ;Good luck.
`

Answer (score 3):

If both `'` are not part of the string, then I recommend using jq for your JSON.

```
jq '.values[][]' file
```

Output:

```
13
```

Answer (score 1):

poor man's query

```
... | sed -E 's/.*"values":\[\[(.*)\]\].*/\1/'

13
```

match the value in double square brackets next to "values" key.